# Automating Web form Filling using Selenium or Mechanize Python with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, mechanize, autofill

Automating Web form Filling using **Selenium** or **Mechanize** Python with Pandas Dataframe.

I am looping through a three columns of pandas dataframe to auto-complete the form for me and submit. Below is the code I came up with. Should I use Selenium or Mechanize and how?

I have a dataframe called checkdatframe with 1010 entries the columns are:

> checkdataframe['CODENUM']

> checkdataframe['NAME']

> checkdataframe['EMAIL']

> checkdataframe['ITEM']

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
for row in checkdataframe.CODENUM:
    if row in '105701':
       url = "https://www.searchitemscompany.com/lookupitems.do?from=Home&locale=en_US"
       br.open(url)
           for column in checkdataframe[['NAME', 'EMAIL','ITEM']]:
               br.select_form('form[action="/lookupitems.do?from=Home&locale=en_US"]')
               br.form['username'] = 
               br.form['emailaddress'] = 
               br.form['product'] =
```

Comment: Where are you using Selenium? Am I missing something?

Comment: Should I use Selenium or Mechanize and how?

Comment: If you want to proceed with Selenium I can join you in your R&D efforts

Comment: I am willing try anything.  So let see about Selenium.  Also, I was thinking, instead of a dataframe.  I can convert the columns I need into a list and use that list to autofill.

Comment: The solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the information into a csv and then run the program

Comment: Use  Selenium for this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).